# OAuth generates expired bearer token

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I've been following the guide for Twitter's 3-legged oauth setup:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

**Step 1: Obtaining a request token**

For their authentication, step 1 requires making a post request containing the base64 encoded public and secret key.

```
key = "CONSUMER_KEY"
secret = "CONSUMER_SECRET"
auth = base64.encodestring("%s:%s" % (key, secret)).replace("\n", "")

data = {}
data["grant_type"] = "client_credentials"
headers = {}
headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + auth
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip"

response = requests.post("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
                         headers=headers, data=data)
```

This first request returns a valid response code 200 along with an access token. The response looks like this:
{u'access_token': u'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHH... ...vncbi', u'token_type': u'bearer'}

**Step 2: Redirecting the user**

This is where the problem is occurring. According to the docs, the user then just needs to be redirected to the authorization url formatted like this:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHH... ...vncbi
```

However when I get to this page I get an error message:
[image]

Is there something I missed? The access_token is being generated without an issue. I'm not sure if this message is showing up because I set something up incorrectly earlier in the process. I'm also not sure how to check if the oauth token has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have been following https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/oauth2/token which is quite different, e.g. only used for public resources and not private like status updates. For the three step one checkout https://gist.github.com/ib-lundgren/4487236 or better yet http://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

If you only want to access public resources like user timelines you can do so via the code below.

```
# OBS: If you want to look at per user details and make status updates
# you want the OAuth1 version. This is only for publicly available
# resources such as user timelines.

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient

# Credentials you get from registering a new application
client_id = '<the id you get from github>'
client_secret = '<the secret you get from github>'

# TODO remove

client_id = 'VVq5UniipB5nXFAqtTA'
client_secret = 'PlaHnaSDbeY4eYkv8XiqxS1nzGWyKoq5WYSNjdeaw'

client_id = 'I1Xi7fOeYnA9jabyvGUaZxY20'
client_secret = 'k5PZpINooRpjAfQccGwLUr2ZMEtRJtoX8cKaooHjKewWupxRBG'

token_url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'

client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id)
twitter = OAuth2Session(client_id, client=client)

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
}
twitter.fetch_token(token_url, headers=headers, auth=(client_id, client_secret))

# Only public resources available to this application-only clients.
r = twitter.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=100&screen_name=twitterapi')
print r.content
```

Make sure you use the github version of the libraries

```
pip install git+https://github.com/idan/oauthlib.git
pip install git+https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib.git
```